# User profiles info in SP overwrites user data in Active Directory

Tags: 2013, user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, ups

Does anyone deal with situation when user profiles info in SP overwrites user data in Active Directory while synchronization option is configured in UPS?

Comment: it seems you have two way synchronisation  enabled

Comment: @AmalHashim, what do you mean by two way sync? There are only import from active directory option and sync option. I've sync enabled. So when I add / change something in AD and run the sync timer job in UPS the old data from user profiles overwrites the new in AD.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#Phase4

Comment: Which properties are getting over written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks anyway, I understand that "SharePoint user profile synchronization does not provide a two-way synchronization for a single property", so in this was the issue.